# Apex Unit test Database.UpsertResult

Tags: apex, unit-test, scheduled-apex

I have this following code. The SubId__c is an external and a unique key in FKS_Subs__c object. This object gets data from FKS_Subs_Delta__c object everyday as a scheduled batch job. If it tries to Insert a record with same SubId__c, it should save one record and the other one I'm expecting to add to SaveUpsert error result. My Unit test doesn't cover this one. Any suggestions will be useful to fix this. How to cover the upsert error part of the code. Thanks

```
List<FKS_Subs__c> subs = new List<FKS_Subs__c>();
for (FKS_Subs_Delta__c delta : scope) {
  FKS_Subs__c sub = new FKS_Subs__c(
    Name = scope.Name,
    SubId__c = scope.SubId__c
  );
  subs.add(sub);
}
try{
  Database.UpsertResult[] results = Database.upsert(subs, FKS_Subs__c.SubId__c.getDescribe().getSObjectField(), false );
    for (Database.UpsertResult sr : results) {
        if (!sr.isSuccess()) {
            for (Database.Error err : sr.getErrors()) {
                Log__c errorLog = new Log__c(
                Origin__c = 'Apex',
                Additional_Information__c = 'FKSDeltaUpsert'
                );
                String errorBody =
                'Error occured: ' +
                err.getMessage() +
                ' on the fields ' +
                err.getFields() +
                '';
                System.debug('errorBody = ' + errorBody);
                errorLog.Error_Body__c = errorBody;
                errorLogs.add(errorLog);
            }
        }
    }
}catch(Exception ex){
   System_Log__c expLog = new System_Log__c(
          Origin__c = 'Apex',
          Additional_Information__c = 'FKSDeltaUpsert',
          Error_Body__c = ex.getMessage()
        );
        errorLogs.add(expLog);
        insert errorLogs;
}
```

My unit test is this

```
static void testSaveError() {
    List<FKS_Subs_Delta__c> deltaList = new List<FKS_Subs_Delta__c>();
    for(Integer i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      FKS_Subs_Delta__c delta = new FKS_Subs_Delta__c(
        Name = 'TestData',
        SubId__c = 1134,
      );
      deltaList.add(delta);
    }
    insert deltaList;

    Boolean hasException = false;

    Test.StartTest();
    FokusDeltaUpsertBatch upsertBatch = new FokusDeltaUpsertBatch();
    upsertBatch.query = 'SELECT Id, Name, SubId__c FROM FKS_Subs_Delta__c';
    try {
      ID batchProcessId = Database.executeBatch(upsertBatch);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      hasException = true;
    }

    Test.stopTest();

    System.assertEquals(true, hasException);
    System.assertEquals(
      database.countQuery(
        'SELECT COUNT() FROM FKS_Subs__c WHERE SubId__c = 1134'
      ),
      1
    );
  }
```

Comment: You're not covering the `if(!sr.isSuccess())` part, or the `} catch(Exception ex) {` part?

Comment: Actually the both, but most important is 
`if(!sr.isSuccess())`

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?